# git amend したコミットの push -f が失敗する

Tags: git

コミットの Author を変更したく、以下の手順で行いましたが、push -f に失敗します。
どうしたらよいでしょうか?

```
$ git commit --amend --author='foo <bar@gmail.com>'
$ git rebase --continue
No rebase in progress?
```

(git log で修正を確認)

```
$ git push origin master -f
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 497 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To ssh://*****
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://*****'
```

git version 2.4.4

Comment: [【Git】non-fast-forwardなコミットのpushが拒否される場合の対処法](http://xvideos.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/21/221600)

Answer (score 2):

push 先のレポジトリの config で、 denyNonFastforwards を false にすると、 `git push -f` で無理やり通せるようになります。

```
[receive]
    denyNonFastforwards = false
```

Comment: レポジトリの設定を変更するのは手段と目的の混同では？皆が共有しているリモートレポジトリの歴史の書き換えを許すのは問題です。